# Telephony Responses Using Dialogflow Webhook

Tags: dialogflow-es

I'm trying to integrate phone gateway with my dialogflow agent. I have a webhook code that takes care of responses for my intents. The agent works perfectly in the google assistant. However, while using telephony gateway I'm only getting the Default Responses and not the webhook ones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is, most likely, that you are using the [actions-on-google](https://github.com/actions-on-google/actions-on-google-nodejs) library to send responses back. This library sends responses that are specific to Actions and don't work with other Integrations.

You can try switching to the [dialogflow-fulfillment](https://github.com/dialogflow/dialogflow-fulfillment-nodejs) library.